# How can get the number of likes shown in app store

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6

I want to know if exist a way to get the number of likes shown in App Store or Game Center.
In this way I can check if a user really likes my application on Facebook.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the iTunes lookup API to get back the info you need in JSON formatted results:
http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

The link you should use for Angry Birds Rio would look like this:
http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=420635506

```
{
    "resultCount":1,
    "results":[
        {
             "artistId":298910979,
             "artistName":"Rovio Entertainment Ltd",
             ...
             "averageUserRating":4.5,
             "averageUserRatingForCurrentVersion":4.5,
             ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Using http-get you can have a look at the itunes page for the app. e.g. for angry birds rio: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/angry-birds-rio/id420635506?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D2

Then if you want to know the total rating have a look here and try to split the String to the relevant part:

```
<div class='extra-list customer-ratings'>
<h4>Customer Ratings</h4>
<div>Current Version:</div>
<div class='rating' role='img' tabindex='-1' aria-label='4 and a half stars, 3113 Ratings'><div><span class="rating-star">&nbsp;</span><span class="rating-star">&nbsp;</span>    <span class="rating-star">&nbsp;</span><span class="rating-star">&nbsp;</span><span class="rating-star half">&nbsp;</span></div><span class="rating-count">3113 Ratings</span>
```